# Search for any text with WHERE ... IN in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, wildcard, psycopg2

I would like to do an SQL query for a wildcard that returns all results.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE column1 IN ('*');
```

The idea would be to inject items by demand, like:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
curs = conn.cursor()

def my_func(filter='*'):
    curs.execute("""SELECT *
                    FROM my_table
                    WHERE column1 IN (%s);""" % filter)
    return curs.fetchall()

my_func(filter=['value 1', 'value 2'])
# or
my_func()
```

The later (`*`) does not work in the `filter` keyword of `my_func`. Is there anything that would?

Comment: What programming language are you using?
Also, 'wildcards' in SQL are typically represented by `%`.

Comment: `select * from my_table where column1 IS NOT NULL;` (or `select * from my_table where 1=1;` )

Comment: @Kenney Python - why does that matter? @wildplasser  I would like to use `WHERE ... IN` if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'inject terms by demand', then? Can you give a use-case example? If you are simply wanting to fetch all rows from `my_table` where `column1` is any value, why not do `SELECT * FROM my_table`?

Comment: Now what language are you calling it from? Python ? PHP ?

Comment: To get all results from that column why not use "SELECT column1 FROM my_table;" ?

Comment: Sorry for causing all that confusion. I hope the updated question is clearer...

Comment: From the psycopg2 documentation: use IN(%s) , and pass an array as argument. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries [under: list adaptation]

Comment: @wildplasser and what kind of array would I need to pass to get all results?

Comment: @n1000 I think wildplasser means a Python `list`, e.g. `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @CraigRinger Agreed. But what item would it need to contain? `[*MAGIC_ITEM*]` to give back all results? I get the feeling my question is not clear at all :D

Comment: @n1000 *sample data* and *expected results* would help a lot, because I can't really understand wha tyou want. It doesn't make sense to have a predicate that matches everything, you'd just leave it out instead. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%'])` is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE true;` (assuming `somecol` is `not null`) which is then equivalent to `SELECT * FROM mytable`. So why would you write the useless clause that matches everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm guessing right: You want a function that you can call to, by default, return everything. But you want to be able to instead filter more narrowly if you pass arguments to the function.

You want the `IN (...)` list equivalent of writing `WHERE somecol LIKE '%'`. i.e. it matches every possible input and is always true. Then you can make `'%'` into a query parameter that you can replace with other values later.

If so: there *is* no equivalent for an `IN (...)` list. There's no way to do that. `somecol IN (1, 2)` is equivalent to `somecol = ANY (ARRAY[1,2])`. There is no value in SQL that is equal to all arguments. It'd make no sense.

There *is* `NULL`, which is unequal to all inputs including its self. So you *can* write:

```
NOT coalesce(somecol NOT IN (NULL), false)
```

... but you will make programmers around the world cry if you do that. I feel dirty even writing it. Also, it'd force you to write your entire filter list negated (i.e. specify the filter as "get rid of these things" not "keep these things"), which might not even be possible and is likely to be impractical.

Trying to leave the query unmodified is futile. Even if it were possible, it's a really bad idea because it's *really* inefficient. You'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Something like (untested):

```
def my_func(filter=None):
    query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        """
    params = []
    if filter is not None:
        query += " WHERE column1 IN (%s)"
        params.add(filter)
    curs.execute(query, tuple(params))
    return curs.fetchall()
```

This is why query builders, ORMs, etc exist. Because SQL's a great language for saying exactly what you want, and a truly awful language for constructing variations on different ways to ask for something.

There are quite a number of such tools for Python. You might want to check them out.

---

Side note: your original code was *horrifically insecure*. *Never* use string formatting in SQL like that. Imagine if someone managed to trick your program into passing the filter value `');DROP TABLE my_table;--` to your code:

```
curs.execute("""SELECT *
                FROM my_table
                WHERE column1 IN (%s);""" % filter)
```

Boom! There goes your table.

This is why you must use query parameters. Your code should've at least been:

```
curs.execute("""SELECT *
                FROM my_table
                WHERE column1 IN (%s);""", (filter,))
```

For details see:

- [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/)
- [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) - read the section on passing query parameters

Comment: Ah thank you so much!! That is just the sort of advice I needed!! `NULL` does not seem to work, but anyway I will rather try now to implement what you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your side note also. I am aware of sql injection. But is this also problematic when my (simulation) program will never be used by anyone else than me? Or should I rather ask a new SO question? :)

Comment: @n1000 If it's truly a closed system - you don't get inputs from the outside world and you're the only user - then sure, write the code as insecurely as you want. Just remember, though... that quick hack prototype you write as a proof of concept will still be running in production 10 years later. If there's any chance of the code escaping in the wild, do it right. Better, do it right anyway, so you don't form bad habits and/or accidentally show bad examples to others who then copy them without understanding their context.